# "Присутствовать в планетарий на лекции"

Tags: словосочетания

"Присутствовать в планетарий на лекции" - от какого слова задается вопрос к "на лекции"?

Answer (score 3):

Присутствовать где? В планетари**и**.

Присутствовать там на каком мероприятии (на чём)? На лекци**и**.

Comment: Присутствовать где? на чём? - на лекции. Обстоятельство со значением дополнения. Так же как и пошёл куда? на что? на концерт.

Comment: Вопрос "где?", конечно, может быть задан и перед ответом "на лекции" или "в планетарии на лекции" - в ситуации неизвестности. Но это вопрос, отвлечённый от падежного окончания слова, к которому его предложено адресовать отдельно; соответствующий вопрос "на чём" в этой ситуации менее практичен (он нужен только в случае переспрашивания непонятого слова - "на чём, на чём?"), но формально он здесь важнее вопроса "где?".

Comment: Понятно, Александр, спасибо за уточнение!

Answer (score 1):

Начнём с того, что правильно "в планетари**и**". В планетари**й** можно, например, приехать на на лекци**ю**.

А вопрос от *"присутствовать":* присутствовать где? на лекции.